# Dynamically add item to DataGridView ComboBox Column by typing in the cell

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

I have a `DataGridView` that has a `ComboBox` column and I must update each ComboBox's possible values when its drop down shows. I also must make the `ComboBox`es capable of having custom typed values. When a new value is typed, it should be added to the list of possible values. The problem is that I get infinitely many `DataError` event triggers (error message boxes), I know how to handle it by just changing a field in the `DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs` object, but I know it is not the correct way to handle it:

```
private void DataGridView1_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = false;
}
```

If I do it in the incorrect way, after selecting a value from the drop down or typing a new value, the `CellValueChanged` is triggered but the closed `ComboBox` does not display the current value but an already existing value (the first in the list).

In the following code the Form subclass is `Form2`, the initial values are stored in the `str` field and the `UpdatePossibleValues` method is called to update the possible values in all the `ComboBox`es inside the only column in the data grid view, a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`:

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing += DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing;

    UpdatePossibleValues();
}

internal List<string> str = new List<string>()
{
    "val1",
    "val2"
};

private void DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, 
    DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell == null ||
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell.OwningColumn == null ||
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name != "column1")
    {
        return;
    }
    var combo = e.Control as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
    if (combo == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    var cb = combo as ComboBox;
    UpdatePossibleValues(cb);
    cb.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown; // this makes the ComboBoxes editable
    cb.Validating += Cb_Validating;
}

private void Cb_Validating(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    var cbo = sender as ComboBox;
    string t = cbo.Text;

    var cell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.CurrentCell;

    // add the value to the list if it is not there
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(t) &&
        !cbo.Items.Contains(t))
    {
        str.Add(t);

        UpdatePossibleValues(cbo);

        cell.Value = t;

        e.Cancel = false;
    }
}

private void UpdatePossibleValues(ComboBox cb = null)
{
    if (cb == null)
    {
        var col = dataGridView1.Columns[0] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn;

        col.Items.Clear();
        foreach (string s in str)
        {
            col.Items.Add(s);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cb.Items.Clear();
        foreach (string s in str)
        {
            cb.Items.Add(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshots:

[image: normal use]

[image: data error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To dynamically add item to `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`:

1. Hanlde `EditingControlShowing` and get the `DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl`
2. Set editing control `DropDownStyle` to `DropDown`
3. Handle `Validating` event of editing control and make sure you attach the event handler just once.
4. Check if the `Text` of the editing control doesn't exists in the items:

   - Add it to data source of the column
   - Then reset data source of the column by setting it to null and assigning data source again.

Notes:

- If you have multiple combo box, make sure you use different data sources for combo boxes and update corresponding data source in validating event.
- If you handle the events using anonymous method, make sure you have a correct assumption about captured variables. To make it simple, you can handle the event using a normal method.

**Example**

The following example shows a `DataGridView` having two `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` which for the second one, you can add new values by typing in the combo box at run-time.

To run the example, create a `Form` and drop a `DataGridView` on a new Form and just copy and paste the following code in the form:

```
private List<String> comboSource1;
private List<String> comboSource2;
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    comboSource1 = new List<string> { "A", "B" };
    comboSource2 = new List<string> { "1", "2" };

    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("C1");
    dt.Columns.Add("C2");
    dt.Rows.Add("A", "1");
    dt.Rows.Add("B", "2");

    var c1 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    c1.Name = "C1";
    c1.DataPropertyName = "C1";
    c1.DataSource = comboSource1;

    var c2 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
    c2.Name = "C2";
    c2.DataPropertyName = "C2";
    c2.DataSource = comboSource2;

    dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(c1, c2);

    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    dataGridView1.EditingControlShowing += dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing;
    dataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;
}
```

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender,
    DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    var dataGridView = sender as DataGridView;
    if (dataGridView?.CurrentCell?.ColumnIndex != 1) return;
    var comboBox = e.Control as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;

    if (comboBox == null) return;
    comboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
    if (!true.Equals(comboBox.Tag))
    {
        comboBox.Tag = true;
        comboBox.Validating += (obj, args) =>
        {
            var column = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)dataGridView.CurrentCell.OwningColumn;
            var list = comboBox.DataSource as List<string>;
            if (list == null) return;
            var txt = comboBox.Text;
            if (!list.Contains(txt))
            {
                list.Add(txt);
                column.DataSource = null;
                column.DataSource = list;
            }
            dataGridView.CurrentCell.Value = txt;
            dataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution works well, but when I try to use the example program you gave using the keyboard there is a bug, the new-row row does not show at the bottom again after using it to insert a new row.

Comment: You can add `dataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);` after setting value.