# How to receive an event when the editing control in a DataGridView moves to another cell?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a ComboBox column in a `DataGridView`. On `EditingControlShowing` I attach an event handler to the `Validating` event of the editing control, handler which can add new strings to the data source of the column which is a `List<string>`. But the editing control is not made on every change of the current cell. If I set the `EditMode` to `EditOnEnter`, I think that the editing control (`ComboBox`) moves to the position of the newly edited cell.

I tried attaching an event handler to the editing control's `VisibleChanged` event but with `EditMode` set as `EditOnEnter` (property I wish the data grid to have), it does not work because a `DataError` event is triggered in the following situation:

1. press Tab until the first cell is focused;
2. in the first row, select a value in the first column's cell using the keyboard (Up/Down keys);
3. press Tab again to focus the second cell, type a value that does not already exist in the ComboBox inside the column;
4. before leaving the cell press Enter.

This is what is shown:

[image: screenshot]

## Code

### Designer

A `DataGridView` with 2 ComboBox columns ("Column1" & "Column2") and `EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter`, Column 1 values are set in the designer to "a", "b" and "c". `Column2.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.ComboBox`.

### Code-behind

```
internal List<string> Options = new List<string>()
{
    "d",
    "e",
    "f"
};

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    (dataGridView1.Columns[1] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).DataSource = Options;
}

private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell == null ||
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell.OwningColumn == null ||
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name != "Column2")
    {
        return;
    }
    var combo = e.Control as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
    if (combo == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    var cb = combo as ComboBox;
    cb.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
    cb.Validating += Cb_Validating;
    cb.VisibleChanged += Cb_VisibleChanged;
}

private void Cb_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var cb = sender as ComboBox;
    if (!cb.Visible)
    {
        cb.Validating -= Cb_Validating;
    }
}

private void Cb_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    var cbo = sender as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
    string t = cbo.Text;

    var cboCell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.CurrentCell;

    if (Options.Contains(t))
    {
        cboCell.Value = t;
        return;
    }
    Options.Add(t);
    cboCell.Value = t;

    dataGridView1.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
}
```

## Update

With `EditMode` set as `EditOnEnter`, it Works if I change the `Cb_Validating` method to this (but this does not answer the question):

```
private void Cb_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    var cbo = sender as DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl;
    string t = cbo.Text;

    var cboCell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.CurrentCell;

    if (!Options.Contains(t))
    {
        Options.Add(t);
    }
    cboCell.Value = t;

    dataGridView1.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
}
```

Comment: You have described a solution and the problems which you have in implementing that solution, but I couldn't get the original problem that you are trying to solve. Maybe if you describe the original problem, the final goal and expected behavior we can suggest a diffenert solution.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I have added steps to reproduce the problem and a screenshot to the question.

Comment: I handled the problem in [my original answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54292713/3110834). So I'll remove my post for this question. Thanks for testing the solution. Let me know if you find any problem in the answer.